# WebSockets not working on Amazon ec2 environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have made a chat application through websockets taking help of this link "http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/" . While it is working perfectly in my own development server, but when I host it on my company's amazon ec2 server it is showing error:
" Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://external ip for amazon:port/"

I am using the server's external IP when trying to connect clients to server and server's internal ip for amazon when executing the server file. I have also put a forwarding rule in my ec2 enabling my port to be accessed in tcp as well as udp.

I also checked my amazon server's ELB and no ELB is in place for my server.

Still it is not working. This is the part of my code for my server's file where sockets are created and the clients are getting connected.

```
    if (isset($this->wsRead[0])) return false;

    if (!$this->wsRead[0] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!socket_set_option($this->wsRead[0], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
        socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
        return false;
    }
    if (!socket_bind($this->wsRead[0], $host, $port)) {
        socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
        return false;
    }
    if (!socket_listen($this->wsRead[0], 10)) {
        socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
        return false;
    }

    $write = array();
    $except = array();

    $nextPingCheck = time() + 1;
    while (isset($this->wsRead[0])) {
        $changed = $this->wsRead;
        $result = socket_select($changed, $write, $except, 1);

        if ($result === false) {
            socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
            return false;
        }
        elseif ($result > 0) {
            foreach ($changed as $clientID => $socket) {
                if ($clientID != 0) {
                    // client socket changed
                    $buffer = '';
                    $bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 4096, 0);
                    //$this->log($buffer);
                    if ($bytes === false) {
                        // error on recv, remove client socket (will check to send close frame)
                        $this->wsSendClientClose($clientID, self::WS_STATUS_PROTOCOL_ERROR);
                    }
                    elseif ($bytes > 0) {
                        // process handshake or frame(s)
                        //$this->log("hi".$buffer);
                        if (!$this->wsProcessClient($clientID, $buffer, $bytes)) {
                            $this->wsSendClientClose($clientID, self::WS_STATUS_PROTOCOL_ERROR);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // 0 bytes received from client, meaning the client closed the TCP connection
                        $this->wsRemoveClient($clientID);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // listen socket changed
                    $client = socket_accept($this->wsRead[0]);
                    if ($client !== false) {
                        // fetch client IP as integer
                        $clientIP = '';
                        $result = socket_getpeername($client, $clientIP);
                        //$this->log($clientIP);
                        $clientIP = ip2long($clientIP);
                        //$this->log($clientIP);

                        if ($result !== false && $this->wsClientCount < self::WS_MAX_CLIENTS && (!isset($this->wsClientIPCount[$clientIP]) || $this->wsClientIPCount[$clientIP] < self::WS_MAX_CLIENTS_PER_IP)) {
                            $this->wsAddClient($client, $clientIP);
                        }
                        else {
                            socket_close($client);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (time() >= $nextPingCheck) {
            $this->wsCheckIdleClients();
            $nextPingCheck = time() + 1;
        }
    }

    return true; // returned when wsStopServer() is called
```

I think this problem revolves around socket_select() function which is not able to select the created socket.
How to make it work?
Please help as I am not able to solve this issue even after much trying.

**UPDATE**

I found out that this problem was arising due to old version of python on amazon. So I changed the python version to 2.6/2.7

Also I substituted socket.io library to run my chat. Its working very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket implementation you are using seems to implement the deprecated Hixie-76 version of the WebSocket protocol, which is no longer supported by Firefox (and Chrome and others).

I suggest having a look at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). This is up to date and well tested.

Comment: Hi oberstet. Thanks for replying. But my project is working on localhost as well as my development server.On chrome,firefox and ie10. Its just not working on amazon ec2. Plus I have to make my code from scratch I cant use any external library which i cant see.

Comment: Are you using port <1024. If so, you need to run under root or set the appropriate specific permission for the PHP executable. On Windows, this is not needed, but Unix. Another potential problem: intermediaries. Use WSS to rule that out.